# Can't seem to fix Eyedropper shortcut

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

For some reason, no matter what file I open, when I press <kbd>E</kbd> I get a contextual menu about the brush's Stroke Mode, but not the color picker/Eyedropper. I have been using the default Shortcuts that came with Blender 2.8.

Changing the menu shortcut to something else causes <kbd>E</kbd> to do nothing, even when I check to make sure that the Eyedropper is setup with it as its shortcut key.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your problem... The shortcut for the eyedropper is <kbd>S</kbd>. To set the shortcut: *Preferences* > *3D View* > *Image Paint* > *Image Paint (Global)* > *Sample Color*.

Comment: Okay! I thought it was listed as "Eyedropper", not "Sample Color" .. that was my mistake. Was getting too frustrated to think of other names it might go by. Thank you!